# Netty file trasfer proxy suffer big connection delay under high concurrency

Tags: concurrency, proxy, netty

I am doing a project of building a file transfer proxy using netty which should efficiently handle high concurrency.

Here is my structure:

**Back Server**, a normal file server just like Http(File Server) example on netty.io which receive and confirm a request and send out a file either using ChunkedBuffer or zero-copy.

**Proxy**, with both NioServerSocketChannelFactory and NioClientSocketChannelFactory, both using cachedThreadPool, listening to clients' requests and fetch the file from **Back Server** back to the clients. Once a new client is accepted, the new accepted Channel(channel1) created by NioServerSocketChannelFactory and waiting for the request. Once the request is received, the **Proxy** will establish a new connection to **Back Server** using NioClientSocketChannelFactory, and the new Channel(channel2) will send request to Back Server and deliver the response to the client. Each channel1 and channel2 using its own pipeline.

More simply, the procedure is

1. channel1 accepted
2. channel1 receives the request
3. channel2 connected to Back Server
4. channel2 send request to Back Server
5. channel2 receive response(including file) from Back Server
6. channel1 send the response got from channel2 to the client
7. once transferring is done, channel2 close and channel1 close on flush.(each client only send one request)

Since the required file can be big(10M), the proxy stops channel2.readable when channel1 is NOT writtable, just like example Proxy Server on netty.io.

With the above structure, each client has one accepted Channel and once it send a request it also corresponds to one client Channel until the transferring is done.

Then I use ab(apache bench) to fire up thousands of requests to the proxy and evaluate the request time. Proxy, Back Server and Client are three boxes on one rack which has no other traffic loaded.

The results are weird:

1. File Size 10MB, when concurrency is 1, connection delay is very small, but when concurrency increases from 1 to 10, top 1% connection delay becomes incredibly high, up to 
   3 secs. The other 99% are very small. When concurrency increases to 20, 1% goes to 8 sec. And it even causes ab to be timeout if concurrency is higher than 100. The 90% Processing delay are usually linear with the concurrency but 1% can abnormally goes very high under a random number of concurrency(varies over multiple testing).
2. File Size 1K, everything is fine at lease with concurrency below 100.
3. Put them on a single local machine, no connection delay.

Can anyone explain this issue and tell me which part is wrong? I saw many benchmarking online, but they are pure ping-pang testing rather than this large file transferring and proxy stuff. Hope this is interested to you guys :)

Thank you!

========================================================================================

After some source coding reading today, I found one place may prevent the new sockets to be accepted. In NioServerSocketChannelSink.bind(), the boss executor will call Boss.run(), which contains a for loop for accepting the incoming sockets. In each iteration of this loop, after getting the accepted channel, AbstractNioWorker.register() will be called which suppose to add new sockets into the selector running in worker executor. However, in 
register(), a mutex called startStopLock has to be checked before worker executor invoked. This startStopLock is also used in AbstractNioWorker.run() and AbstractNioWorker.executeInIoThread(), both of which check the mutex before they invoke the worker thread. In other words, startStopLock is used in 3 functions. If it is locked in AbstractNioWorker.register(), the for loop in Boss.run() will be blocked which can cause incoming accept delay. Hope this ganna help.